# monetdb: export query result

Tags: sql, monetdb

How to export monetdb query result (e.g. to csv file)?

Manual says:

> Copy into File
>
> The COPY INTO command with a file name argument allows for fast
>   dumping of a result set into an ASCII file. The file must be
>   accessible by the server and a full path name may be required. The
>   file STDOUT can be used to direct the result to the primary output
>   channel.
>
> The delimiters and NULL AS arguments provide control over the layout
>   required.
>
> *COPY subquery INTO file_name [ [USING] DELIMITERS
>   field_separator [',' record_separator [ ',' string_quote ]]] [ NULL AS
>   null_string ]*

https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/CopyInto

I'm trying with various syntax but with no result.

example query:

```
select * from test;
```

example failures:

```
copy select * from test into test.csv;
copy "select * from test" into test.csv;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK. Missing apostrophe and full path. Also delimiters useful

```
copy select * from test into '/home/user/test.csv' using delimiters ',';
```